# How to get a char from user in terminal?

Tags: kotlin

How can i get input from terminal for character in Kotlin? I tried using readline(), but throws me an error

```
fun asciiConverter(){
    print("Enter the character to convert into ASCII : ")
    var characterVariable : Char = readLine()
    println("ASCII value is : ${characterVariable.toInt()}")
   }
```

The above code throws me an error, `Type mismatch. Required : Char, Found : String?`
I don't know how to change a string to character. Is there any other function like `readline()` to get character? Please let me know.

I think i have no other way to get a string and change it to character array. Please correct me if  I am wrong. I tried running this code below, it ran successfully.

```
fun asciiConverter2(){
    print("Enter the character to convert into ASCII : ")
    val characterVariable = readLine()?.toCharArray()
    println("ASCII value is : ${characterVariable?.get(0)?.toInt()}")
}
```

(I am new to programming and new to stack overflow. sorry for bad English)

Comment: you are reading line its contain multiple characters, so instead of `var characterVariable : Char` should be `var characterVariable : String?`

Comment: Hi Hayi Nukman. Thanks for the report.

I tried using your suggestion. The program runs without compilation errors. But i get runtime error while using the program

```
Enter the character to convert into ASCII : f
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

Comment: on your code, you are trying to convert it to Int.... or number, while string f is not a number... you need more codes to process it... while my suggestion is since you are reading the line which contain string not a single char...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun readLn() = readLine()!!
fun readCharAndPrintAscii() {
    println("Enter the character to convert into ASCII : ")
    val charFromUser = readLn().firstOrNull()?.let { it.toInt() }
    println("ASCII value is  $charFromUser")
}
readCharAndPrintAscii()
```

- `readLine()` will return `String?`, the function `readLn()` will be your template for reading other types later.
- `firstOrNull()` will return `Char?` as first element
- `?.let { it.toInt() }` will return the value of this character as `Int` value.(Ascii)

now, you can use `readLn()` for another input for example:

```
fun readInt() = readLn().toIntOrNull() ?: println("Not an Int.")
readInt()
```

For more examples and tricks look [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/competitive-programming.html#more-tips-and-tricks).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    asciiConverter()
}

fun asciiConverter(){
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter the character to convert into ASCII : ")
    val characterVariable : Char = reader.next().single()
    println("ASCII value is : ${characterVariable.toInt()}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Naor Tedgi for fast reply. Your program worked like charm. 

I know Kotlin does support java and I dont want to use java in this program. Is there any other way to get character form user only by using Kotlin?

Please let me know.